# Factory in $interval only gets called once?

Tags: angularjs

I have this $interval polling an API for some data every second. I have a factory to do this for me and I set it up in an $interval indefinitely:

```
$interval(pollingFactory.getStartedStatus($routeParams.session).success(
        function(reply){
            console.log(reply);
        }), 1000, 0, true);
```

The issue with this is that it only works once. It doesn't repeat indefinitely like it should...

Comment: Wrap the call to getStartedStatus in a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getStartedStatus()` is being invoked immediately before being passed to $interval. Wrap it in a function...

```
$interval(function() {pollingFactory.getStartedStatus($routeParams.session).success(
    function(reply){
        console.log(reply);
    }
}), 1000, 0, true);
```